# passing more than 1 parameter in metro style app c#

Tags: microsoft-metro

I have a **class student** with 2 variables one string **name** and other integer **roll**.
using
`this.frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1),s1);` //s1 is an object of class student
I am trying to pass an object to page1

But I am not able to access any of the variables of s1 on page1.

in the NavigatedTo method of Page1 I have written:

```
student x= e.Parameter as student;
student n= new student();
n.name=x.name;
```

in whichever I try to access object x variables it throws a "NullReferenceException unhandled by the user code"
"object reference not set to an instance of an object"

not able to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `student x = e.ExtraData as student`? Here is some relevant [Msdn doco.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs.extradata.aspx)